# NSTableView + NSTextView = Disaster :(

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

This is driving me a bit crazy..

Down below is a screenshot of my program so far.

On the right is an NSTableView (view-based). This is where the user can select a document they want to work on.

On the left is the NSTextView. Text will be displayed depending on what item they choose in the NSTableView.

There are also big plus and minus buttons for creating/deleting new items in the tableview.

Simple right? I wish.

[image]

Right now I have it so the tableview gets data from a mutable array. The mutable array contains objects of a class called DocumentItem. The DocumentItem just has two strings, one for the document text and one for the document title.

**What works so far:**

When I manually add objects to the array using code, I am able to freely switch through the documents and the textview will update accordingly.

**What doesn't work:**

When the user switches to a different document, I want to call the NSTableView `replaceObjectAtIndex` method save the changes that they have made to the object in the array.

**How my code works so far:**

The mutable array is stored in a data class. The data class is a shared class and is referred to in my code as theDATA.

I have a thread looping in my class that has the textview. In my tableview class I have a method called blastToScreen that will change a BOOL called shouldBLAST to YES.

Here is the code in my TableController class to set the BOOL to YES:

```
- (void) blastToScreen{

    theDATA.blasttext = [[theDATA.globaldoclist objectAtIndex:[tablevieww selectedRow]] doccontents];
    theDATA.shouldBLAST=YES;

}
```

Here is the shouldBLAST method in my looped thread(in a different class from the textview). Please note that the if-statement that says `if(theDATA.switchedrow)` is there to make sure that certain code gets runned only when a user switches their row in the tableview.

```
if(theDATA.shouldBLAST){

        if(theDATA.switchedrow){
            DocumentItem * itemr = [theDATA.globaldoclist objectAtIndex:theDATA.lastindex];

            NSLog(@"(%li) prev content - >%@",(long)theDATA.lastindex,itemr.doccontents);

            itemr.doccontents=textvieww.string;

            NSLog(@"(%li)adding content - > %@ <- to %@",theDATA.lastindex, itemr.doccontents,itemr.docname);

            theDATA.switchedrow=NO;
            [theDATA.globaldoclist replaceObjectAtIndex:theDATA.lastindex withObject:itemr ];

            NSLog(@"changed: - > %@",[[theDATA.globaldoclist objectAtIndex:theDATA.lastindex] doccontents]);

        }





             textvieww.string=theDATA.blasttext;
             theDATA.shouldBLAST=NO;
        NSLog(@"changed: - > %@",[[theDATA.globaldoclist objectAtIndex:theDATA.lastindex] doccontents]);
        theDATA.lastindex=theDATA.selectedrow;



    }
```

**Here's the weird part about all this:**

According to the NSLog statements I set up, my code works for a split second and then resets.

Down below is what the console says. ignore the (0). that is just talking about the last selected index.

What it is saying is that the text before switching was nothing(fine). It is saying that it is adding the text "Potato" to that array(still fine). Then, the first time I fetched the object from the array it shows that it successfully changed to "Potato"(Still fine). Then when I tried to fetch the SAME exact data a few lines later, it returned nothing. :(

I feel like the issue resides somewhere in my TableController class. [Here's a link](http://pastie.org/10420003) to the code in my TableController class.

Here's what the console returned:

```
2015-09-14 17:17:46.024 Simplicity[4801:432580] (0) prev content - >
2015-09-14 17:17:46.025 Simplicity[4801:432580] (0)adding content - > Potato <- to Untitled
2015-09-14 17:17:46.025 Simplicity[4801:432580] changed: - > Potato
2015-09-14 17:17:46.025 Simplicity[4801:432580] changed: - >
```

I really hope you guys can help me. I tried pretty much everything I could to solve this issue.This is holding me back from finishing my software.

Comment: it's tough to help out without knowing what `theDATA.globaldoclist` is, can you log that value?

Comment: @aug2uag globaldoclist is the shared array that I'm using for the nstableview.

Comment: Another disaster is the length of your issue presentation.  Make it brief.  Nobody is going to spend more than 30 seconds reading an issue brought by somebody else.

Comment: @ElTomato lol sorry. I just don't know where else to turn and I had trouble making the question condensed without leaving out details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, the `doccontents` property of your `DocumentItem` class is `strong` (or `retain`) when it should be `copy`.

From the [docs for the `string` property of `NSText`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSText_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSText/string) (from which `NSTextView` inherits):

> For performance reasons, this method returns the current backing store of the text object. If you want to maintain a snapshot of this as you manipulate the text storage, you should make a copy of the appropriate substring.

So, if you're just keeping a reference to that same object, when the text view's content is changed, the content of the object you've got a reference to also changes. You need to make a private copy.

Comment: Thanks so much! I can't believe a 2-second change fixed it. I need to read up on properties some more. You're a life saver!